# Syntax error when trying to print complex output

Tags: python

Can anyone please help me to rectify that syntax in python. Output is given as following:

```
ip='180.211.134.66'
port='123'

print ({"http":"http://"+ip +":"+ port +"})"
```

I would like to get output like this:

```
({"http":"http://180.211.134.66:123"})
```

Comment: Do you need the whole thing as a string or do you need a dictionary with key as `http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the whole output as string...

You should either use single quotes to contain the string or escape the double quotes.

Use this:

```
ip='180.211.134.66'
port='123'

print '({"http":"http://' + ip + ':' + port + '"})'
```

OR

```
print "({\"http\":\"http://" + ip + ":" + port + "\"})"
```

Output:

```
({"http":"http://180.211.134.66:123"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) for this:

```
ip='180.211.134.66'
port='123'
data = {"http":"http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port)}
print '({0})'.format(data)
```

In one line:

```
print "({0})".format({"http": "http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port)})
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two double quotes are unnecessary. remove them and you have :

```
ip='180.211.134.66'
port='123'

    data = { 'http' : 'http://' + ip + ':' + port }
    print str(data)

    # output like this ({"http":"http://180.211.134.66:123"})
```